# Text from file to array with conditions in Python

Tags: python, string, file, python-3.x

```
    file = open("smth.txt","r")
    pom = list()
    string = ""
    for lines in file:
        for letter in line:
            if letter in "0123456789":
                pom.append(int(letter))
            if letter == "T" :
                pom.append(True)
            elif letter.isalpha() == True:
                string += letter
       pom.append(string)
    file.close()
    print(pom)
```

Idea of code should be simple from a line from .txt is: 2,abc,True. The result should be [2, 'abc', True] so numbers convert to int, letters into str, and "True" into True. I have problem with that True, now the result is [2, True, 'abcrue'] what condition should be used on "True" ?

Comment: can't you use split??

Comment: Python will not automatically un-pluralize your variable names. If you `for lines in file:` then the code in the loop needs to do something with `lines` not `line`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to go this complex: you can use split

```
>>> my_str = "2,abc,True"
>>> my_list = my_str.split(',')
>>> my_list
['2', 'abc', 'True']
```

now you can put condition to convert to int ,str or bool

Answer (score 0):

if you want to modify your code use add this condition before ture condition

```
if letter in "True":
   break
```

or you can use split()